# command to git commit and add untracked files - at the same time?

Tags: git

For some reason, I thought that doing:

```
git commit -a -m "commit something here"
```

the `-a` part would already ADD files, but I was wrong (by fact, because it means ALL and not ADD) and by example (because files were not added).

So, I still need to:

```
git add . 

git commit -a -m "whatever"
```

Isn't there a way to commit with an option that adds untracked files automatically ?

Comment: Do you mean untracked files?  Your first example should be fine if all of the files are already tracked.

Comment: From the manual: "-a, --all: Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not affected."

Comment: I mean untracked yes.

Comment: Thanks cbuckley. So -a as nothing to do with add. Thks - I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to commit untracked file automaticaly. You have to manually add your file with `git add <filename>`

Comment: `git add . && git commit -a -m "something"` - would be the most near option perhaps... ?

Comment: Yup, you can try to do a shell command that would do both command

Answer (score 2):

It's a useful operation, but you will have to add an alias along the lines of this (using a shell function):

```
[alias]
    commitall = "!f() { git add -A; git commit -m $1}; f"
```

Comment: Care to explain why not just `commitall = 'git add -A; git commit -m "$1"'`?